# Passing body header with PHP

Tags: php, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying make a Vimeo-API to upload subtitles/captions, following this guide: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks#uploading-a-text-track-step-3

The guide gives 4 steps, I'm stalled in step 3.

Step 3: 
`To upload the text track, take the value of the link field from Step 2, and make a PUT request to this location: PUT https://api.vimeo.com{link}`

Here is my code:

```
require 'Vimeo/autoload.php';
use Vimeo\Vimeo;

$client = new Vimeo("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxx");


include __DIR__ . '/Vimeo/autoload.php';

$clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$scope = "public";
$userId = 9999999;
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);
$token = $lib->clientCredentials($scope);


$lib->setToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');


$videos = $lib->request("/videos/99999999/texttracks", ["type"=>"captions", "language"=>"pt-BR", "name"=>"legenda"], "POST");
$link = $videos["body"]["link"];
$videos = $lib->request("/videos/99999999/texttracks/", ["link"=>$link, "body"=>"https://paste.ee/r/E3Q1K/0"], "PUT");

echo "<pre>".var_export($videos, true)."</pre>";
```

Output:

```
array (
  'body' => NULL,
  'status' => 405,
  'headers' => 
  array (
    'Server' => 'nginx',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Allow' => 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',
    'X-Vimeo-DC' => 'ge',
    'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
    'Via' => '1.1 varnish',
    'Content-Length' => '0',
    'Date' => 'Wed, 22 May 2019 07:11:58 GMT',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'X-Served-By' => 'cache-bwi5150-BWI, cache-lax8642-LAX',
    'X-Cache' => 'MISS, MISS',
    'X-Cache-Hits' => '0, 0',
    'X-Timer' => 'S1558509118.323164,VS0,VE80',
    'Vary' => 'Accept-Encoding',
  ),
)
```

So, the problem *occur* in this line: 
`$videos = $lib->request("/videos/99999999/texttracks/", ["link"=>$link, "body"=>"https://paste.ee/r/E3Q1K/0"], "PUT");`

As you can see, the output `body` is `NULL`. How can I set up correctly body header? I'm trying make this API for three days, here is my last hope, I'll be very glad if you could help me.

Thank you

Comment: _“In the body of the request, include the contents of text track in WebVTT format.”_ - I don’t see you doing that, you appear to be providing a URL instead.

Comment: `$videos = $lib->request("/videos/335720713/texttracks/", ["link"=>$link, "body"=>"file.vtt"], "PUT");` does not work, the `output` is the same.

Comment: A file name and the actual content of a file are still two different things.

Comment: So, what must I change to make the code work? Also, the actual content of the fiel.vtt, is a webvtt valid caption.

Comment: Well provide the file _content_, instead of its name or a URL … If you want to read it from that file at that point, use `file_get_contents`.

Comment: `$videos = $lib->request("/videos/335720713/texttracks/6442106", file_get_contents("teste.vtt"), "PUT");` Unfortunately, this way isn't working too... The output is the same but the contains now: `'HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed' => '',`

Comment: Guess that’s because you are making that request to the wrong URL to begin with … _“To upload the text track, take the **value of the link field from Step 2**, and make a PUT request **to this location**”_